# How to create script that toggles one value in synclient?

Tags: bash, shell-script, synclient

I use `synclient touchpadoff=1` to disable touchpad and `synclient touchpadoff=0` to enable touchpad.

```
$synclient | grep TouchpadOff
    TouchpadOff             = 1
```

I'd like to create script that will toggle this value. Then I will bind to key in OpenBox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
if synclient -l | egrep "TouchpadOff.*= *0" ; then 
    synclient TouchpadOff=1 ; 
else 
    synclient TouchpadOff=0 ; 
fi
```

*For reference a third setting, `TouchpadOff = 2`, disables only tapping.*

---

Or a **one-liner**:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=$(synclient -l | grep -c 'TouchpadOff.*0')
```

---

**References:**

- [Arch Touchpad Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics)

Comment: Thx, didn't know about egrep. Btw is it possible to create oneliner?